# Why should we use $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(iframeUrl)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-sce

I am new to AngularJS. I tried binding iframe src with Angular controller.

html:

```
<iframe class="mini-graph" ng-src="{{iframeUrl()}}"></iframe>
```

controller js:

```
$scope.iframeUrl = function(){
    return "http://www.google.co.in";
};
```

This doesn't work. But if I change my controller to:

```
$scope.iframeUrl = function(){
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.google.co.in");
};
```

it works.

I don't know what's the magic happens with `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl`. It would be great if some one could explain it.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, AngularJS prevents binding `ng-src` to untrusted external resources, such as an external URL. The call to `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl` returns a special wrapper object for the external URL to mark the URL as trusted.

Comment: Does $sce.trustAsResourceUrl make the url call with CORS headers?